# When I run "php TestRunner SiteTest.php" it doesn't see extends class

Tags: php, yii

I tried to run an example from the book:"Agile Web Application Development with Yii1.1 and PHP5". Command line:"php TestRunner SiteTest.php". File "SiteTest.php" has a line: "class SiteTest extends WebTestCase". It writes: "Class 'WebTestCase' not found in SiteTest.php. May be someone read this book and knows why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're bootstrapping the framework properly, your only issue should be that you should be extending CWebTestCase, not WebTestCase.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebTestCase